# Switching between difference tab and listview

Tags: android, listview, tabs

My App in android contain more than 7 activity first activity is splash screen, then start Main activity 2 other activity contain tab ,when i try to call tab activity  from Main activity 2  by button the App is crashed,i change tab activity to list activity when i try to call list activity its same error again.
Please Can anyone help me?
BR.

this is first splash page

```html
package com.almadar.evo.app.evo_app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressBar pgr;
    int Progress=0;
    Handler h=new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pgr =(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
         new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    Progress += 20;
                    h.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            pgr.setProgress(Progress);
                            if (Progress == pgr.getMax()) {
                                //pgr.setVisibility(4);
                                Intent in= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
                                startActivity(in);
                               finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                       // e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

this second page

```html
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }


    public void bupostclick(View view) {
        Intent in= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),postpaid1.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }

    public void bupreclick(View view) {
        Intent in1= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),pre1.class);
        startActivity(in1);
    }


}
```

this is third page contain button to take me to list view page

```html
public class pre1 extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pre1);



    }

    public void home(View view) {
        Intent in= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(in);
        finish();
    }

    public void mainrefill(View view) {

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(pre1.this,refil3.class);
        startActivity(intent1);


    }


    public void home1(View view) {
    }
}
```

this is list view page

```html
public class pre2 extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

ListView l;
    String[] service={"1","2","3","4","5"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        l= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,service);
        l.setAdapter(adapter);
        l.setOnItemClickListener(this);




    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {
        TextView temp= (TextView)view;
        Toast.makeText(this,temp.getText()+""+i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
```

this is error when APP is crash

```html
 --------- beginning of crash
05-04 09:57:23.290 12144-12144/com.almadar.evo.app.evo_app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.almadar.evo.app.evo_app, PID: 12144
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.almadar.evo.app.evo_app/com.almadar.evo.app.evo_app.refil3}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.almadar.evo.app.evo_app.refil3.onCreate(refil3.java:22)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please paste the crash report and for using ListActivity there should be a listview on your layout with id: `android:id="@android:id/list"`

Comment: i add the code and crash error you can check thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code in your prev2

```
l= new ListView(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.l);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,service);
    l.setAdapter(adapter);
    l.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```